Screenshot of the Week #63 has the wrong game tag in the Hall of Fame, but the tag for the game doesn't exist. How can I fix this?
In the Screenshot of the Week - Hall of Fame specifically, the winner of that week's Screenshot of the Week contest has a picture of the winning screenshot alongside the tag declaring what game the image is from.
The winner of contest #62 was Super Mario 3D All-Stars, according to the Hall of Fame. This seems to be valid. However, the listed game under the winner of contest #63 appears to be incorrectly tagged as also being from Super Mario 3D All-Stars, despite being from the game Psychonauts 2.
I have included an image that shows the issue at hand — please note the matching tags under Game:

I was going to edit this to change the tag from super-mario-3d-allstars to psychonauts-2, but it seems to not exist. Now I am not sure what to do to go about fixing this issue.
Should I have instead used the psychonauts tag? 
Where can I go to get a new tag created? Is it possible to create one myself, or does this have a high reputation barrier? 
Is creating a tag simply for the purpose of labeling a single screenshot a worthy enough cause?

Also note you can use the [tag:some-tag-name] markdown to create tag links in your posts :-)

Ah, now I get your issue: yes, the tag in the Hall of Fame was incorrect. Someone (possibly me) copied the former entry and forgot to change the tag :)
It is fixed now. Thanks for bringing it up!


Nice! Glad we got there in the end :)

Just to address some questions not about the Screenshot competition:


Where can I go to get a new tag created? Is it possible to create one myself, or does this have a high reputation barrier?

You can create tags from the Ask Question page, as you have over 300 reputation points, which is the minimum required to unlock tag creation privileges.
For those with less than 300 reputation we also have a generally accepted workaround, as defined in this faq question: I want to ask a question about a game which has no tag yet, how should I tag it?

Is creating a tag simply for the purposes of labelling a single screenshot a worthy enough cause?

Creating a link to a tag is a separate process to creating a tag. I can link to [tag:oignsoignsiogn] for example: oignsoignsiogn. Instead of a "Not Found" error, you simply get taken to the questions page - where it states that no questions are currently tagged with oignsoignsiogn.

I'm confused as to what the problem is?
Batophobia won contest 62 (theme Bosses and Villains) with this post of a picture from super-mario-3d-allstars. This winning post was then featured in the previous winner section of contest 63 as per usual with the appropriate tag.
Batophobia then won contest 63 as well (clearly cheating, pls ban this hacker /s) with a picture from psychonauts-2. This was then featured in the previous winner section of contest 64 with the appropriate tag.
So, everything looks fine to me. Sure, there isn't an actual tag on the main site for psychonauts-2, but that doesn't prevent me from labeling it with the tag on meta. It just means if you click on it, it will go to a page saying no questions exist with that tag.
If you tried to create a tag for it, say by adding the tag to a random question, then removing the tag from that question, the tag would get auto deleted as it has no questions associated with it. If you really want to ask a question about Psychonauts 2 so that the tag exists, that's fine, just make sure it is a good on topic question. Otherwise, it doesn't matter overly much, and I wouldn't be surprised if there were quite a few other winners that were from games that did not have a tag here (eg. my sim-ant submission for the 90's contest).

Here, look on the hall of fame https://i.imgur.com/0r1Du5T.png

I've clarified my post, I hope the information is sufficient now to highlight the problem.

I agree, that Batophobia is clearly a cheater.
